# Urlify regex and Detect URLs in text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, url

***Hello everyone***

Now what works for me it just links (www && http), links like : https://www.facebook.com/  -- Such links do not work for me.

this is code:

```
   $scope.urlify=function(text){

        var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)|(www[^\s]+)/g;   

        return text
            .replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
                return '<a href="http://' + url + '" target = "_blank">' + url + '</a>';    
            }).replace("http://http://", "http://");
      }//urlify function
```

[image]

What do I need to change the code?
thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesnt make a lot of sense since you are replacing your regex text with a url. Did you try to use .match() instead?

Comment: I got on with the things, thanks:   The answer is: add one more : .replace("http://http://", "http://").replace("http://https://", "http://");